# Calculate matching background-color of element placed above DIV with a background gradient

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, clip-path

Implementing a design, i ran into a tricky problem.

**OVERVIEW**

I have a menu with items, each of which contain a panel that opens upon hover. The content of each of these is dynamic, so the width of each panel can be (and is) different. The panel has a gradient as a background color:

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%);
```

Directly above the panel i want to display an arrow pointing upwards towards the menu item. I did this by placing a DIV within the menu item element and positioning it, so that it sits at 50% minus the arrow's width, thus being centered neatly underneath the menu item. In cases where the panel exceeds the outer container's width, it gets shifted to the left using negative `margin-left` which works fine, making sure the panel is within the outer container of the page.

[image: Example]

**THE PROBLEM**

The arrow's color should blend smoothly into the panel. As you can see in my example however, the color of the arrow (being a fixed background color) will blend into the background of the panel either more or less. The wider the panel is, and the much further it is positioned to the left, the more the gradient color differs from the arrow's color, which means that the arrow doesn't blend into the gradient background nicely.

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR**

Trying to solve this, i considered/tried three things:

1. Using `clip-path` on the arrow element, to cut out a triangular shape, with the arrow element having the same width and the same gradient as the panel. This however does not work, because i need the arrow to have a 1px white border on the top-left and top-right angles.
2. Copying the panel into a CANVAS and then reading the pixel color at the desired position. This fails entirely, it only seems to work with images.
3. Writing a function that i can pass two arguments: a width and an arrow position. The function would then calculate the most optimal background color for the arrow by approximating the gradients color at the given arrow position based on the panel's background gradient.

   ```
    calculateArrowColor: function(divWidth, arrowPosX) {

        const color1 = [78, 138, 188];
        const color2 = [49, 112, 162];
        const gradientSteps = divWidth / 2;
        const stepSize = 1 / gradientSteps;
        const arrowPosStep = arrowPosX / divWidth;
        const arrowColor = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            const color1Value = color1[i];
            const color2Value = color2[i];
            let arrowColorValue;
            if (arrowPosStep < 0.5) {
                const currentStep = arrowPosStep / stepSize;
                const colorDifference = color1Value - color2Value;
                arrowColorValue = color1Value - (currentStep * colorDifference);
            } else {
                const currentStep = (arrowPosStep - 0.5) / stepSize;
                const colorDifference = color2Value - color1Value;
                arrowColorValue = color1Value + (currentStep * colorDifference);
            }
            arrowColor.push(Math.round(arrowColorValue));
        }

        return `rgb(${arrowColor.join(",")})`;

    };
   ```

Unfortunately my function doesn't work and i can't figure out why. It returns values out of range that make no sense.

Maybe my approach isn't that clever.

I am looking for a good solution for this tricky problem.

Here is a workable snippet: (click the panel to shift it to the left, right-click it to increase its width)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.panel').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('margin-left', '-200px');
  }).on('contextmenu', function(e){
    $(this).css('width', '600px');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #369;
}
ul > li {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div.label {
  position: relative;
}
div.arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}
div.arrow:before, div.arrow:after {
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -11px;
  border-width: 11px;
}
div.arrow:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #69c;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-width: 10px;
}
div.panel {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%);
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <span>MENU ITEM</span>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Could you explain more about solution 1 which would seem the most straightforward. The 1px border doesn’t seem to matter in the image you show as there is a white background. Why is the border needed?

Comment: In the solution for which you show some code, I cannot see where you compensate for the angle. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AHaworth The panel has a box-shadow. Unfortunately. Thus the white border is visible. On top of it, i would probably have to stretch the hidden gradient area to the same height as the panel, and inverse it, but upwards and z-indexed behind the menu, so that the non-clipped area (the triangle) obtains the correct colors. Regarding the angle, it's a linear gradient, so it should be no issue.

Comment: Just for understanding: the arrow is positioned top:1px so that it overlaps the panel and is supposed to create the illusion of panel and arrow being one single element. I considered using clip-path for a specific upper area of the entire panel element, but then i would have to fake a border on top and the whole shadow issue becomes a problem.

Comment: I still feel we should be able to use clip paths. Could you show more code, the relevant HTML and related CSS since they seem to affect a solution. Preferably as a runnable snippet.

Comment: Thanks. I was rather hoping to find a purely mathematical solution to the problem, as clip-path still has me relying on certain browser capabilities. But i'll try to come up with a runnable snippet.

Comment: I added a workable snippet to my question.

Comment: Hi, I can’t see the box-shadow

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. Fixed it. Relevant to note: depending on contrast settings under these particular circumstances the issue with the border might be barely present to predominantly present, i assume.

Comment: I don't understand why the angle isn't an issue - yes it's a linear-gradient but at an angle.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It took me a while to brain myself around that. Now i get it. There must be a way to calculate this, but i guess the clip-path approach is more safe because i assume every browser will render gradients slightly differently. Or maybe that's a false assumption. I am not sure.

Comment: Been looking into this. Why not put  `arrow` and `.panel` in a container element and have them share the same `background-attachment: fixed` `background-image: your-gradient`? That way the entire calculation becomes obsolete, no JS required. Let me know if something like this [Codepen solution](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYmZNmW) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I just did that, take a look!

Comment: Thank You, but unfortunately that solution changes the way my panel's gradient expresses, based on its position in the page. The design doesn't allow it.

Comment: I wanted to apply the `clip-path` approach. I could have added a second arrow with transparent background but white border and positioned it on top of the other one. Unfortunately when using `clip-path` the `box-shadow` will no longer render. There are approaches to circumvent this which require changing the HTML structure, which is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you aim to use JS anyway, to calculate the color, I suggest you let CSS do the color selection but use a bit of JS to find out where to draw the arrow head.

This snippet ignores the arrow element, which probably shouldn't be in the DOM anyway as it doesn't have particular meaning but is just a visual clue.

Instead it puts an after pseudo element on the panel, with almost the same dimensions and background gradient and positions it just above the panel. clip-path is then used to create the pointy bit.

To get the white outline to the arrowhead it as a before pseudo element background white and clips that to be just slightly bigger than the colored arrow head. [This snippet shows it in red as it is otherwise difficult to see it against the rather faint shadow].

Note, the arrow head has a gradient to its coloring, not just one color, but it's too small to notice really.

You may like to parameterise the size for the arrow - you'll see 14px and variations all over the place here, would be more flexible if set at a CSS variable.

```html
<style>
  ul,
  li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  ul {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #369;
  }
  
  ul>li {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  div.label {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  div.panel {
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%);
  }
  
  div.panel::before {
    content: '';
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 15px);
    z-index: 1;
    clip-path: polygon(0 15px, calc(var(--midpoint) - 14px - 1px) 15px, var(--midpoint) 0, calc(var(--midpoint) + 15px) 15px, 100% 15px, 100% 16px, 0 16px);
  }
  
  div.panel::after {
    rdisplay: none;
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -14px;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 14px);
    z-index: 1;
    clip-path: polygon(0 14px, calc(var(--midpoint) - 14px) 14px, var(--midpoint) 0, calc(var(--midpoint) + 14px) 14px, 100% 14px, 100% 15px, 0 15px);
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <span>MENU ITEM</span>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
  function positionArrows() {
    const labels = document.querySelectorAll('.label');
    for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
      const labelLeft = labels[i].getBoundingClientRect().left;
      const labelWidth = labels[i].getBoundingClientRect().width;
      const panel = labels[i].querySelector('.panel');
      const panelLeft = panel.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      labels[i].style.setProperty('--midpoint', (labelLeft - panelLeft + labelWidth / 2) + 'px');
    }
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.panel').on('click', function() {
      $(this).css('margin-left', '-200px');
      positionArrows();
    }).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
      $(this).css('width', '600px');
      e.preventDefault();
      positionArrows();
    });
  });
  positionArrows();
  window.onresize = positionArrows;
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I am trying to get it to work with a 10px arrow. I am confused by the midpoint variable.

Comment: I do have to reposition the arrows after load anyway, because the menu panels get shifted and moved around according to whether it's needed because they exceed container boundaries or not. Are you using the variable because you cannot access or change pseudo element styles via JS ?

Comment: Altogether this is a very cool way to reach the desired effect without sacrificing any of the relevant design features. However, i am wondering if there is a way around using the midpoint variable as it looks like a honeypot for browser compatibility problems to me.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by 'honeypot for browser compatibility problems'. You can check when browsers started to allow CSS variables on caniuse.com. roughly they have been supported in all but IE since somewhere 2014-2016. If that is a worry, then instead of using the variable, write the clip-path directlyvia JS - though you may find clip-path supported at about the same time depending on browser.

Comment: I may have added to the confusion! When I say 'write the clip-path directly' it will of course have to be into a style element as you can't style a pseudo element directly. Personally I find it much clearer to have a CSS variable. If you prefer then of course have a style sheet element which you rewrite each time you calculate the position of the arrow.

Comment: Good point! Yeah, i ran into that problem before, trying to change a `clip-path` in a pseudo-element. I actually just implemented the whole thing and it looks very good! Bravo! Good thinking!! The only problem is that when the user zooms, there is a thin hairline just underneath the top of the panel (you can see it here in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f13zwphd/1/ if you zoom in 10% or more). However, i actually i just realized that the arrow-bordering element wouldn't need to include the top border of the panel, as the panel already has one.

Comment: Yes, this is an edge effect created when the system is mapping one CSS pixel to several screen ones - bits get left over smetimes when there is a fraction. If still a problem, clip the after psseudo element one more pixel down to overlay the main panel background.

Answer (score 1):

Does the following suit your needs? I used `clip-path` and tweaked with the borders, the main key is the `background-attachment: fixed;`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.panel').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('margin-left', '-200px');
  }).on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    $(this).css('width', '600px');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #369;
}

ul>li {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.label {
  position: relative;
}

div.arrow {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%);
  min-width: 22px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  z-index: 10;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin-left: -11px;
  /*negative margin-left which is half of the width of the element to be positioned*/
}

div.arrow:before,
div.arrow:after {
  border: solid #fff;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-width: 13px;
  top: -13px;
}


/*
div.arrow:after {
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #69c;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border-width: 10px;
}*/

div.panel {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%);
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 120px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9.5px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="label">
      <span>MENU ITEM</span>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
      <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a very interesting approach, but it doesn't work for me unfortunately, because the panel's gradient now changes relatively to where the panel is positioned in the page. The design demands the panel to have a 135deg linear gradient going from top left to bottom right, as defined here `linear-gradient(135deg, #579AD1 0%, #1F679D 100%)`